# Copying an Object with numerous other Classes Used

Tags: java, object, clone

Imagine I have a class `AntHill` which needs to be cloned so the original can be modified without affecting the clone.  However, class `AntHill` contains references to `Ant`s which reference each other.  How would you recommend I clone the 'AntHill' object without serializing and deserializing it?  Speed is a priority.

Comment: I resolved it by creating a map of old ants to new ants, cloning everything and updating references.  However I was wondering if there was a simpler solution.

Comment: Have you considered providing a proxy view or an alternate implementation that no-ops the methods that change state?  The clients using the `AntHill` and `Ant` objects need not know that such a proxy or implementation even exists, but if they try to change it, nothing would happen.  Maybe just drop a message in the logs explicitly stating that the attempted change was ignored.

Comment: The problem is that I need to change the `Ant`s in both `Anthill`s without affecting the other `Anthill`s.